# How specify php2wsdl @param cardinality?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'd like to generate a WSDL such that SoapUI would mock a request as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="https://v121d164.prevnet/webservices/server.php">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:myService soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
      <code xsi:type="xsd:string">?</code>
    </ser:myService>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

PHP2WSDL documentation have examples for instance variables:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @maxOccurs 0
 */
```

But it says nothing about params.
I've tried to use

```
/**
 * @param string
 * @maxOccurs 0
 */
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and use it as a parameter for your method. You can define cardinality for properties of that class with @minOccurs tag:

```
Class MyServiceInput
{
   /**
    * @var string
    * @minOccurs 0
    */
   public $str;
}

class MyService
{
   /**
    * @soap
    * @param MyServiceInput $inputParam
    */
    public function myMethod($inputParam)
    {
    }
}
```